# Error with form_tag for Rails 4.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to set up an AJAX call to update a partial in my HTML, so I made a form_tag with :remote => true to point to.  However, I'm dealing with data outside of a model, and the data that I'm looping through has to be contained within an internal loop because form tags interfere with table structure.  How do I fix my form_tag to fix my error?

in the partial _body.html.erb

```
<!-- this form tag seems to cause the problem -->
<%= form_tag('front/update_table_info', :remote => true, :method => post) %>

    <table id = "prescription-table">

        <tr id="table-head">
            <th>header_1</th>
            <th>header_2</th>
        </tr>

    <% @profile_data.each_with_index do |value, value_index| %>

        <!--this if block is for pagination-->
        <% if value_index > 19 %>
            <tr style = "display: none" >
        <% else %>
            <tr>
        <% end %>

                <td><%= value[:text_1] %></td>
                <td><%= value[:text_2] %></td>
            </tr>
        <% end %>

        <caption>
            <!-- pagination stuff -->
        </caption>

    </table>
<% end %>
```

edit:  This is causing the error ".../_body.html.erb:44: syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting $end"

Comment: Remove the last `<%end%>`.This will fix the error.

Comment: Why?  Don't I need an end for both the form_for and the each block?

Comment: If your form has a `do` then you need `<%end%>` otherwise you wont need.

Comment: If I render this form_tag now, will it stop at the end of the view or will it cascade back and continue rendering the rest of the document?  I.E. should I make it a do - end block to just render this view?

Comment: I would suggest do-end simply because that gives you an obvious starting point and an obvious ending point instead of leaving it up to the code to decide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot your "do" after your form_tag. This is what you want most likely.

```
<%= form_tag('front/update_table_info', :remote => true, :method => post) do %>

    #form stuff
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your form_tag line needs a `do` at the very end. While `form_for` would have a block variable as well, `form_tag` has no block variable, but it still needs `do` to start the block.